# Is it possible to have a WCF/WAS service using net.tcp port 80 and IIS on the same port?

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, was, net.tcp, tcpportsharing

Does the TCPPortSharing service permit me to have a WAS activated TCP-Based service on the same port as IIS's port 80?

The picture below shows net.tcp at port 808.  Can I change this to port 80?  If the answer is "no" then am I misunderstanding the benefit of the tcpportsharing service?

[image: Image of IIS Binding]

Answer (score 0):

The default port for net.tcp scheme that is published is 808. Similar to SSL 443. 
This means that you don't need to specify 808 when sending a request to a net.tcp endpoint from WCF and give this information to all your clients. You can host multiple services listening on the default port using Windows activation service. 
IIS will use port 80 by default but there is nothing stopping you from making net.tcp on 80 but you cannot share the port on different scheme.